# Parse realtime update

Tags: ios, parse-platform, real-time

I'm creating an app using parse.com. For this ios app i need a have some kind of live/real time update of a specific column in a class. How can i do that. i've read a little about the push notifications, but it seems like they are not that precise. For this app it requires that the notification of an update on this column is precise. I've also looked at pubnub, but i'm not sure what would be the best solution for such a simple real time update of a single number in parse.

What would be the best solution for such?

Comment: Can you elaborate what realtime means to you ? Parse requests have usualy latency around 0.3-1 second, also depending a bit on your location as the primary datacenter is in US. Updating and reading out column from database would be simple yet hard to guess if it will work well enough for your scenario without further info.

Comment: I have a column called number in my object which is suppose to be updated in realtime. i could just create an nstimer, but wouldnt that be a lot of unnecessary requests if the object row has not been updated.

Comment: As for object update notification service, I don't think there is such thing at the moment, parse only provides modification date so you can check if it was changed and get new value at the same time, but you would have to actively check it - query the object. You may use notification to certain degree as you've suggested. Do your numbers change a lot quickly and often ?

Comment: it probably changes every 3rd minute, but it is extremely important that the end user is provided with the updated number as precise as possible. i've read something about integrating pubhub or other real time services, but cant seem to find some kind of documentation for it